# MVC3 lock textbox based on a selection on a dropdown menu

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am making a form using ASP MVC 3 and I am new not only to web development but to ASP.NET MVC as well.

The user will have the chance to either Pick one of the given questions from a dropdown menu, or write their own.

What I am trying to do, is to block the text field where the user will type a question in case the user previously selected any question from the dropdown menu.

I can use either JavaScript or use MVC  (I preferably would like to use MVC code, but JavaScript can work as well).

```
<tr> 
<td width="40%" height="31">
<div align="right"><strong>Security question:</strong></div>
 </td>
 <td width="60%" height="31"> 
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PickSecretQuestion, new[] {

   new SelectListItem() { Text = "---select a question --- or create your own below --", Value = "createNew"},
   new SelectListItem() { Text = "Mother's Maiden Name?", Value = "Mother's Maiden Name?"},
   new SelectListItem() { Text = "Father's Middle Name?", Value = "Father's Middle Name?"},
   new SelectListItem() { Text = "What High School did you attend?", Value = "What High School did you attend?"},
   new SelectListItem() { Text = "First company you worked for?", Value = "First company you worked for?"}

   }
    </td>  
    </tr>

     <tr> 
     <td width="40%" height="31">
     <div align="right"><strong>Or create one here:</strong></div>
     </td>
     <td width="60%" height="31"> 
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecretQuestion)
         <span style="color:Red">  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SecretQuestion </span>
     </td>  
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely *much easier* with **jQuery**.  Here's how I'd go about this:

```
$('#yourDropDownId').change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('selectedIndex') == 0)
        $('#yourTextBoxId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
        $('#yourTextBoxId').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

This is logic that really should be handled on the *client* instead of making a trip to the *server*.  It definitely makes sense to utilize **the power and simplicity of jQuery**.

In your View, you can set `id`s for your DOM elements by using the `htmlAttributes` object for the helper methods.  Here's the change you'd make to your `TextBoxFor()`.  This would set your `id` to "yourTextBoxId".

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecretQuestion, new { id = "yourTextBoxId" })
```

Comment: This might be a silly question, how do I assign ID's to elements in MVC (I am assuming I should add the ID's somewhere after the @ sign.

Comment: @user1144347 See the second parameter of my `TextBoxFor()` method above.  It has an object that you can set properties to HTML attributes.  The HTML id would be the `id` property, as set in my example.

Comment: @user1144347 Did that answer your question?  Did you get this code working?

Comment: Sorry for getting back at this time.  We had issues on the Controllers and decided to push back all the views development.  YES! It did work! thx!