# MVC4 disable textbox on selection of a dropdownlist item

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdown, viewbag

I have a textbox and a dropdown on my form. When "MessageDate" item is selected from the dropdown the textbox should be disabled. The value for messageDate is stored in Viewbag in the controller

Controller:

```
ViewBag.dd_search = dd_search;
switch (dd_search)
{
 ...
 case "msgDate":
     modelml = modelml.Where(m => m.Message_Date == Convert.ToDateTime(searchText)).ToList();
 break;
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
@Html.TextBox("searchText", ViewBag.searchText as string, new { @class = "form-control" })                               
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
 @Html.DropDownList("dd_search", new SelectList(EBA_AJAX.ViewModels.DropDown.DD_Message_Search(), "Value", "Text", ViewBag.dd_search), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
```

The javascript:

```
<script>
 $('#ddsearch').change(function ()
{
    if ($(this).attr('@ViewBag.dd_search') == "msgDate")
    $("#txtsearch").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
    $("#txtsearch").removeAttr('disabled');
});
</script>
```

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234928/mvc3-lock-textbox-based-on-a-selection-on-a-dropdown-menu) post for reference but still not getting the desired output. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from other oddities, I don't know why do you reference ViewBag.dd_search attribute with an @ in your event comparison. Remove that @ and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with you code i hope this will work for you its working on my machine you did not use id attribute in HTML and your access in JS that's why it's not working.
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fm").change(function () {

```
            if (Your Condition)
                $("#txtsearch").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            else
                $("#txtsearch").removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });
</script>


     <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBox("searchText", "asad", new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtsearch" })
        </div>
<div class="col-md-2">
 @Html.DropDownList("dd_search", new SelectList(EBA_AJAX.ViewModels.DropDown.DD_Message_Search(), "Value", "Text", ViewBag.dd_search), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control fm" })

</div>
```